# Boxen project manifest isn't resolving $repo_dir

Tags: puppet, boxen

I'm trying to use Boxen to setup our dev environment. We have a number of repos that we want to pull down and run a script to get started. We landed on a convention: repos have a `scripts/` directory with a `bootstrap` script that needs to be run.

It looks like this would be possible with the `exec` command. But in order to tell it what to run, I have to access the repo's directory. Other scripts use `$repo_dir` or `${boxen::config:srcdir}/${name}`. I've tried each of these, and a number of different styles of `exec`, to no avail.

### The Manifest

```
class projects::hero {

  include ruby

  boxen::project { 'hero':
    ruby          => '2.0.0',
    source        => 'myorg/hero'
  }
  ->
  Exec {
    command       => '$repo_dir/scripts/echo'
  }
  ->
  notify {'hero is running at $srcdir':}
}
```

This is simpler than the stated goal. The scripts need to be run within the directory they reside. So my first  (and hopefully eventual) manifest would have something like this for the `exec` step:

```
->
exec { 'running bootstrap on hero':
  command         => '$repo_dir/scripts/bootstrap',
  cwd             => '$repo_dir/scripts'
}
```

### The script

For right now, `scripts/echo` is super simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Echo File!"
touch `date`
```

Since the output isn't really going to be seen, we're making a file with the date so we can observe this side effect and know that the script actually ran.

### Calling boxen

I just call this project directly from the `manifests` directory:

```
Chris:manifests chris$ boxen hero
```

### The output

```
Warning: Scope(Class[Boxen::Environment]): Setting up 'hero'. This can be made permanent by having 'include projects::hero' in your personal manifest.
Error: Could not find resource 'command => $repo_dir/scripts/echo' for relationship from 'Boxen::Project[hero]' on node chris.local
Error: Could not find resource 'command => $repo_dir/scripts/echo' for relationship from 'Boxen::Project[hero]' on node chris.local
```

This is also true if I try `${boxen::config::srcdir}` instead. Looking at other examples, these variables are used and seem to work. Am I calling it wrong? Is there a different variable I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed two mistakes in your manifest here:

```
->
Exec {
    command       => '$repo_dir/scripts/echo'
}
->
```

The first is that you've capitalized the first letter of exec. In puppet language this means you are specifying a default for all subsequent exec resource definitions ([docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defaults.html)). This is not a resource definition itself, therefore resource ordering can not be applied, hence the error.

Another mistake is the use of single quotes in combination with variables. Single quoted strings are interpreted as literals. In other words, `'$repo_dir'` is interpreted literally as `$repo_dir` while `"$repo_dir"` is interpreted as the contents of the varialbe `$repo_dir` ([docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_datatypes.html#strings)).

Hope this helps,

Good luck